# Linear Algebra proof on Eigenvectors and Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, proof-explanation

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of *A*. Furthermore, the vector $\vec{x}$ is the eigenvector of *A* corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$, and $\vec{x}$ is the fixed point of *B*. Prove that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of *AB* and *BA*, and the vector $\vec{x}$ is the corresponding eigenvector of *AB* and *BA*.

So just from reading the question I get the idea that either $A=B$ or either $A$ or $B$ is an identity matrix of size $n\times n$. The part of the question that really throws me off is where it states that $\vec{x}$ is a fixed point of $B$ considering that $\vec{x}$ is a vector. Can anyone help guide me through this problem?

Comment: By "$\vec{x}$ is a fixed point of $B$", I'm guessing you mean $B\vec{x} = \vec{x}$?

Comment: A fixed point is a eigenvector with eigenvalue 1.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not true that $A=B$ or that either is the identity.

Hint:
If $x$ is a fixed point of $B$ and an eigenvector of $A$ for eigenvalue $\lambda$, calculate $ABx$ and $BAx$.

Answer (score 3):

It needn't be the case that $A=B$ or that $A$ or $B$ be the identity matrix. For example take $n=2$, let $A=2I$, let $B$ be reflection in the $x$-axis and let $\vec x = (1,0)$, then $\vec x$ is a fixed point of $B$ and an eigenvector of $A$.

What this question wants you to prove is that if $A \vec x = \lambda x$ and $B\vec x = \vec x$, then $\vec x$ is an eigenvector of both $AB$ and of $BA$. My advice would be to evaluate $AB\vec x$ and $BA \vec x$ and see what happens.

Comment: So I was able to show $AB \vec{x}$ pretty easily once I was given this hint (thank you very much for that!) I just want to make sure that my thought process for $BA \vec{x}$ is correct. If I have $B \vec{x} = \vec{x}$ and I know that $\vec{x}$ is an eigenvector for some eigenvalue $\lambda$ then I can say
 
$B \vec{x} (\lambda) = \vec{x} (\lambda)$

Since $\lambda$ is a constant then $B (\lambda) \vec{x} = (\lambda) \vec{x} $

Given $A \vec{x} = \lambda \vec{x}$ then $B (A \vec{x}) = \lambda \vec{x}$.

Comment: Your notation isn't what I'm used to, but you seem to have the right idea. Since $A\vec x = \lambda x$ you have $BA \vec x = B(\lambda \vec x)$, and then since matrices preserve scalar multiplication, you have $B(\lambda \vec x) = \lambda B \vec x$, etc...

Answer (score 1):

A (nonzero) fixed vector is just an eigenvector for eigenvalue$~1$. And an eigenvector of $M$ for$~\lambda$ is a nonzero vector such that on the subspace of dimension$~1$ that it spans, multiplication by$~M$ acts as multiplication by the scalar$~\lambda$.

By what is given $A$ acts on that subspace as multiplication by$~\lambda$, and $B$ as multiplication by$~1$. Then on that subspace both $AB$ and $BA$ act as multiplication by$~\lambda$ (scalar multiplications commute); that's all. You have no information whatsoever about what $A$ and $B$ do outside that subspace (nor do you need such information).